# SharePoint 2010 how to display a picture within a picture

Tags: html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a map of the UK that I have broken down by region. What I want to do is click on an area of the map which will then open a window to a zoomed in picture of the region selected. Clicking on locations will give me details.

I believe that I should use Iframes but have never done this. I do not have access to SharePoint Designer 2010 just 2007. I also do not have access to Google Maps etc.

I know how to use the hot spots and have already created hot spots in my regional maps, I just need to know how to combine the map within the map. I also need to know how to load it into SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the image in a content editor webpart.

then create an image map in html

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml

should do the trick. then to click in areas build an image map again and use javascript to display the information